# Java Point2D.Distance different than Pythagoras Theorem?

Tags: java

I noticed that Point2D.Distance is actually returning a different result than if you manually calculate the distance between two points using Pythagoras Theorem.

The distance between (565.0, 575.0) and (25.0, 185.0) is mathematically 665.4. When using Distance to calculate this the returned value is 666.108.

**Is there any technical explanation for this?**

EDIT: My apologies, everyone. I had an error in my own calculations. After so little sleep I'm looking for ghosts in the machine. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Java indeed seems correct. Maybe you have a rounding error? See here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance+between+(565.0,+575.0)+and+(25.0,+185.0)

Comment: Please share the code for both approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram Alpha and Java cannot be wrong at the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the correct distance is 666,108099...

You should check your Theorem and calculus :p
(and in doubt, trust the machine...)

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by `Point2D.distance()` is the correct mathematical result to three decimal places.

This code illustrates the computation:

```
     double s = Point2D.distance( 565.0, 575.0, 25.0, 185.0 );
     System.out.println( s ); // 666.1080993352356
     System.out.println();

     double dx = Math.abs( 25.0 - 565 ); 
     double dy = Math.abs( 575.0 - 185.0);
     System.out.println("|x2 - x1| = " + dx );  // |x2 - x1| = 540.0
     System.out.println("|y2 - y1| = " + dy );  // |y2 - y1| = 390.0

     System.out.println("sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) = " + Math.sqrt( dx*dx + dy*dy ));
     // sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) = 666.1080993352356
```

The implementation of `Point2D.distance()` is fairly easy to read:

```
public static double distance(double x1, double y1,
                              double x2, double y2)
{
    x1 -= x2;
    y1 -= y2;
    return Math.sqrt(x1 * x1 + y1 * y1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say but Point2D.Distance is right. You are probably having a mistake in your computing for

V1(x1,y1) = (565.0, 575.0)

and

V2(x2,y2) = (25.0, 185.0)

The distance is The square root of: **(abs(x1-x2))^2 + (abs(y1-y2))^2**

And this value yields exactly **666,10809933523552675465753614979**

Answer (score 1):

Did the math out. I got `666.108` as well. I suspect you made a math error somewhere.

Lets assume a triangle `ABC` such that `AC` defines the distance between the points.

We need the other two sides:

`AB` is `575-185=390`

`BC` is `565-25 =540`

`390` squared is `152100`

`540` squared is `291600`

Adding these together gives `443700`
The square root of this is `666.108`